# Magento custom Delivery date inside fax field in database

Tags: magento

we have integration with external program that retrieves orders from Magento Store unfortunately only one table "sales_flat_order_address" and we can't add  own columns because XML is a restrictive (Linnworks)

Table "sales_flat_order_address" stores customer data and FAX field that interests me
Table "sales_flat_order" stores other information custom column such as "shipping_date"

Both tables have a common key "entity_id"

Please help, how can I add the date to the field "fax"
SQL Trigger? if so how would he look like I've never done anything like this.
Additional query, swapping session (Fax <=> delivery_date) during the order process.
Regards